# How to pass field value to nested object from parent when using automapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to map objects with automapper.

My input model:

```
public class Input
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<NestedObject> NestedObjects { get; set; }
}
public class NestedObject
{
    public string SomeString { get; set; }
}
```

My output model:

```
public class Output
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<OutputNestedObject> OutputNestedObjects { get; set; }
}

public class OutputNestedObject
{
    public int InputID { get; set; }
    public string SomeString { get; set; }
}
```

My mapping code:

```
[Test]
public void TestNesting()
{
    var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<Input, Output>()
            .ForMember(x=> x.OutputNestedObjects, src=> src.MapFrom(x=> x.NestedObjects))
            ;
    }).CreateMapper();

    var input = new Input()
    {
        ID = 111,
        NestedObjects = new List<NestedObject>()
        {
            new NestedObject(){SomeString = "sometext"},
        }
    };

    var output = mapper.Map<Output>(input);

    Assert.AreEqual(input.ID, output.ID);

    var inputNested = input.NestedObjects.First();
    var outputNested = output.OutputNestedObjects.First();

    Assert.AreEqual(input.ID, outputNested.InputID);
    Assert.AreEqual(inputNested.SomeString, outputNested.SomeString);

}
```

Now i'm having AutoMapperMappingException:

`Unmapped properties:
InputID`

I want to get object of Output with nested OutputNestedObject with id of Input object. How to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-value-resolvers.html#passing-in-key-value-to-mapper

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a mapping from NestedObjects to OutputNestedObjects.

Automapper won't map Objects without explicit mapping if some properties are missing.

Comment: But how to pass id from input to NestedObject?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround i'm using this solution:

```
var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<NestedObject, OutputNestedObject>();
    cfg.CreateMap<Input, Output>()
        .ForMember(x => x.OutputNestedObjects, src => src.MapFrom(x=> x.NestedObjects ))
        .AfterMap((src, dest) =>
        {
            foreach (OutputNestedObject nested in dest.OutputNestedObjects)
            {
                nested.InputID = src.ID;
            }
        })
        ;
}).CreateMapper();
```